# Local Variables and GC

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I'm trying to wrap my head around private variables in Javascript, temporary variables, and the GC. However, I can't quite figure out what would happen in the following situation:

```
MyClass = function() {
   this.myProp = new createjs.Shape();

   var tempVar = this.myProp.graphics;
   tempVar.rect(0, 0, 10, 100);
   tempVar = null;

   var isDisposed = false;
   this.dispose = function() {
      if (isDisposed) return;
      isDisposed = true;
   }
}
var anInstance = new myClass();
```

My intention was to have *isDisposed* represent a private status variable, and *tempVar* be a use-and-throw variable.

Would *tempVar* get marked for GC? Would *isDisposed* be marked for GC too? How is the GC to know when I'm trying to declare a temporary variable meant for disposal, and when I'm trying to have a private variable within the object?

I tried to test the following in Chrome, and it seems as if *tempVar* never gets GC-ed as long as an instance of myClass exists. So I'm not sure what to believe now. I am incredulous that every single local variable that I create for temporary usage will exist in scope for the lifetime of the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript does not have strongly typed objects. By setting `tempVar` to null, you're not declaring that you don't want to use it any more or marking it for collection as in Java or C#, you're merely assigning it a (perfectly valid) value. It's a trap to begin thinking that just because you made tempVar an "instance" of an object, that the variable is in fact an object and can be treated as such for its whole lifetime.

Basically, variables are just variables in Javascript. They can contain anything. It's like VB or VBScript in that regard. Scalars do undergo boxing in many cases (as in `'a|c'.split('|')` making the string into a String) but for the most part, forget that. Functions are first-class objects meaning you can assign them to variables, return them from functions, pass them as parameters, and so on.

Now, to actually destroy something in Javascript, you either remove all references to it (as in the case of an object) or, in the case of an object's properties, you can remove them like this:

```
delete obj.propertyname;
// or //
delete obj[varContainingPropertyName];
```

To expand on that point, the following two code snippets achieve *identical* results:

```
function abc() {window.alert('blah');}
var abc = function() {window.alert('blah');}
```

Both create a local variable called `abc` that happens to be a function. The first one can be thought of as a shortcut for the second one.

However, according to [this excellent article on deleting](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/) that you brought to my attention, you cannot delete local variables (including functions, which are really also local variables). There are exceptions (if the variable was created using `eval`, or it is in Global scope and you're not using IE <= 8, or you ARE using IE <= 8 and the variable was created in Global scope implicitly as in `x = 1` which is technically a huge bug), so read the article for full details on `delete`, please.

Another key thing that may be of use to you is to know that in Javascript only functions have scope (and the `window` in browser implementations or whatever the global scope is in other implementations). Non-function objects and code blocks enclosed in `{ }` do not have scope (and I say it this way since the prototype of `Function` is `Object`, so functions are objects too, but special ones). This means that, for example, considering the following code:

```
function doSomething(x) {
   if (x > 0) {
      var y = 1;
   }
   return y;
 }
```

This will return `1` when executed with `x > 0` because the scope of variable y is the *function*, not the *block*. So in fact it's wrong and misleading to put the `var` declaration in the block since it is in effect (though perhaps not true practice) hoisted to the function scope.

You should read up on [closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) in javascript (I cannot vouch for the quality of that link). Doing so will probably help. Any time a variable's function scope is maintained anywhere, then all the function's private variables are also. The best you can do is set them to `undefined` (which is more "nothing" than "null" is in Javascript) which will release any object references they have, but will not truly deallocate the variable to make it available for GC.

As for general GCing gotchas, be aware that if a function has a closure over a DOM element, and a DOM element somewhere also references that function, neither will be GCed until the page is unloaded or you break the circular reference. In some--or all?--versions of IE, such a circular reference will cause a memory leak and it will *never* be GCed until the browser is closed.

To try to answer your questions more directly:

- `tempVar` will not be marked for GC until the function it is part of has all references released, because it is a local variable, and local variables in Javascript cannot be deleted.
- `isDisposed` has the same qualities as `tempVar`.
- There is no distinction in Javascript for "temporary variables meant for disposal". In newer versions of ECMAScript, there are actual getters and setters available, to define public (or private?) properties of a function.
- A browser's console may provide you with misleading results, as discussed in the article on deleting with Firefox.
- It's true, as incredible as it may be, that in Javascript, so long as a variable exists within a closure, that variable remains instantiated. This is not normally a problem, and I have not experienced browsers truly running out of memory due to tiny variables lying around un-garbage-collected. Set a variable to `undefined` when done with it, and be at ease--I sincerely doubt you will ever experience a problem. If you are concerned, then declare a local object `var tmpObj = {tempVar: 'something'};` and when done with it you can issue a `delete tmpObj.tempVar;`. But in my opinion this will needlessly clutter your code.

Basically, my suggestion is to understand that in coming from other programming languages, you have preconceived notions about how a programming language *ought* to work. Some of those notions may have validity in terms of the ideal programming language. However, it is probably best if you relinquish those notions and just embrace, at least for now, how Javascript actually works. Until you are truly experienced enough to confidently violate the advice of those who have gone before you (such as I) then you're at greater risk of introducing harmful anti-patterns into your Javascript code than you are likely to be correcting any serious deficit in the language. Not having to Dispose() stuff could be really good news--it's this nasty pervasive task that Javascript simply doesn't require from you, so you can spend more time writing functionality and less time managing the lifetime of variables. Win!

I hope you take my words as kindly as they are meant. I don't by any means consider myself a Javascript expert--just that I have some experience and a solid competence in understanding how to use it and what the pitfalls are.

Thanks for listening!

Comment: About delete: A good reference seems to be  http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/ Seems that only properties, or undeclared variables, can be deleted. As long as a variable is declared using 'var', delete doesn't work on it. So *delete tempVar* would not work.

Comment: Than you for the information, @Cardin, and for curing my laziness in bothering to go look it up. Updating now.

Comment: i see, so that's the case with local variables in JS. My desire to remove local vars was to eliminate debugging issues with remnant/crossover vars referenced outside normal scope. But if that's standard in JS I guess i'd have to adapt to the culture. :) I leapt into JS w/o reading up any books on it yet, so i guess my coding style must have been really odd here haha. +1 for your really detailed answer.